# VBA code to compare two columns with colour and compare it with another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns AA, AB and AF where I have to compare the AA and AB column with the AF column for all the rows individually. Macro should first check AA and AB column and find which of the column have the Amber colour and it should compare that column (only if that Amber column have value as "Critical") with the corresponding AF column to check the AF column have the days less than 335 days or not.

This query first compares AA and AB column and which one have amber colour and with the amber colour it will check the value "Critical" if that value is found then check the correspoding AF column having the date less than 335 days or not. Somehow query is not working. Please help me on this.

```
Sub EUDA_New()


Dim Critical As Range
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim amberColor As Boolean

StartDate = Date

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE")

    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Critical In .Range("AB11:AB" & LRow)

        amberColor = False

        If .Range("AA" & Critical.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then

            Set Critical = .Range("AA" & Critical.Row)

            amberColor = True

        ElseIf .Range("AB" & Critical.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then

            amberColor = True
        End If


        If amberColor And Critical.Value = "Critical" Then

            If IsDate(.Range("AF" & Critical.Row)) Then

                If DateValue(.Range("AF" & Critical.Row)) < StartDate - 335 Then

                    .Range("AF" & Critical.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Else

                .Range("AF" & Critical.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        End If
    Next Critical

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add what error pops up when you run this script ?

Comment: *Somehow query is not working*. This is too broad and unclear. Please, be more specific.

Comment: working fine now, Thanks